# Mysql dump unable to unzip mysql file

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am using following code for  mysql dump.
It is creating file `database-date.sql.gz`

```
date=`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`
user=myuser
password=password
backup_dir=/var/backups/mysql/
file=database-$date.sql.gz


mysqldump -u$user -p$password database --max_allowed_packet=512M | gzip - > $backup_dir$file`
```

here problem is it is showing file format is unknown format or damaged.
I thing it is due to file is not properly created.
What changed shoud i do to make proper backup of large database file.

Comment: Sounds like a disk space problem. How big is the partition where you're storing the dump and how much disk space do you have?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic                                                                                 
                   `df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        30G   13G   17G  43% /`

Comment: What about during the end of the dump? Does the command show you're getting near 100% use?

Comment: no idea facing same problem.

Comment: Can you try with another database, for example, `mysql` database?.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

File: `mysql_dump_test.sh`

```
date=`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`
user=$mysql_user
password=$mysql_password
backup_dir=/path/to/file/
file=$database-$date.sql.gz
database=mysql

$ mysqldump -u $user -p$password $database --max_allowed_packet=512M \
            | gzip - > $backup_dir$file
```

Test result:

```bsh
$ zcat /path/to/file/mysql-20000101000001.sql.gz | head -20
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: mysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.18

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `columns_priv`
--
```